# What is the OR operator in emacs regexps?

Tags: regex, emacs

The manual says to use '\|', as in a\|b matches a or b. But when I use it with regexp builder or align-regexp e.g. with, "True\|False", it doesn't recognize "True" or "False". I get the following message:

```
Wrong argument type: integer-or-marker-p, nil
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use `\|` and not `|`?

Comment: Something odd is happening, because if you try True\|False with highlight-regexp it works. In regexp-builder it does not. Perhaps groups and or don't work in the builder which seems lame.

Comment: I don't think that the regular expression is your problem.  Post the emacs lisp.

Comment: I found same as @justinhj with emacs-version 21.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I'm sure it says "\|" and not "|". FWIW, "|" doesn't work either. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash

Comment: Post the exact sequence of commands you're having trouble with or copy-paste the Lisp code you're trying to get to work (I can't even tell which!). The “or” operator is `\|`. Strings and regexps are orthogonal in Emacs Lisp, so if you put a regexp in a string, you need to write e.g. `"True\\|False"`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Use double escape: `\\|`

**A Few Additional Notes:**

Emacs has 2 escaping styles, one in EmacsLisp the other when used in commands, 
ie. from the `M-x` prompt (`rgrep`, `occur`, …)

> In EmacsLisp, use the double backslash  `\\|`

…

> From `M-x …` use a single backslash `\|`

… As a side note, when writing embedded EmacsLisp, for example in yasnippet dynamic expansions, you have to use a quadruple backslash: `\\\\|` (to escape the double backslashes.)

Always avoid this (if possible), for example in yasnippet you can provide mode related emacslisp, without the additional escaping, via a `.yas-setup.el`

Answer (score 5):

For further details, see the discussion of `'\'` and strings in the elisp manual section 34.3.1.1 "Special Characters in Regular Expressions"

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Regexp Special")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: What is binding `M-:`?

Comment: If you mean "how do you type it?" it's the Meta modifier and the Colon key together.  On my keyboard Meta is my "Alt" key and the colon is a shifted semicolon key, so I have to hold Shift as well.  If you mean "what command is it bound to?" then ask Emacs -- type `C-h k M-:`

Comment: You can alternatively type `C-h i g (elisp)Regexp Special` to jump directly to a node in the manual like that one.