# "Or" operator in emacs regexp with `M-x occur`

Tags: regex, emacs

I've wanted to get an overview of my Python program, so I ran:

`M-x occur`

and for the regexp I've supplied

`(def)|(class)`

which failed to match anything.

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443095/what-is-the-or-operator-in-emacs-regexps) post, and tried

`(def)\\|(class)`

but this failed to match anything either...

How do I get `M-x occur` to match `class` or `def`?

Comment: `(` and `)` match parentheses in Emacs regexps. For grouping you use `\(` and `\)`. The alternation operator is `\|`. Double backslashes are only needed when writing regexps as double-quoted strings (because a backslash is special in string syntax as well as regexp syntax).

Comment: Sorry but come on....You tried `|` and you tried `\\|`...are you too lazy to try `\|` yourself?

Comment: Dualinity: The escaping requirements of strings and regexps in Emacs can be confusing at first for fairly obvious reasons, so there's no need to be insulting. After all, I'm quite certain that at least some of *your* 50+ questions about Emacs could have been answered by simply searching the built-in manual yourself, rather than 'lazily' asking other people to tell you the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use single backslash (without parentheses, or you should escape parentheses as well):

```
def\|class
```